# Java 7 ForkJoinTask and Akka 2.0

Tags: java, java-7, akka, fork-join

Is there any plan to leverage java 7 util.concurrent's ForkJoin APIs or, expose similar API in Akka?

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking on the Akka mailing list - http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've been working with Doug Lea to improve ForkJoinPool for Akka, and I'm going to embed the new version for Akka 2.0: http://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/1728

Read this for a summary from Doug: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2012-January/008987.html

But we won't be exposing the raw API of ForkJoin, that's what the ForkJoin framework is for.

Cheers,
√